# What is the recommended way to handle methods that require a higher API in Android?

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android project and ran into the problem, that I would like to use a method that requires a higher API than my min level.
Now, all I would like to do is implement the method so that only devices which support it calls that method.

What's the cleanest way to implement that. I have seen that some people use an if-else statement like this:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
// Do something fancy
} else {
// Do something regular
}
```

But to me this looks not very "aesthetic". Is this the way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Thats pretty much the way to do it

Comment: The reason I dont like this approach is because then you have to check this for every single method you implement.

Comment: There shouldn't be all that many methods you need to check. For many such methods you can avoid doing this by using the support library.

Comment: Or you can create a static helper class so you just need to call that instead. I.e helper.DoSomething() where DoSomething does the check and runs the correct code. That way all of you SDK checks are in one place.

Comment: ok, you convinced me. I am going to go with a static helper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that's pretty much it but you can condense this logic into a single place should the `if else` conditions get out of hand. If you are using dependency injection (DI) then the 'module' (see the `@Module` definition under DI projects such as Square's ['Dagger'](https://github.com/square/dagger)) would be the place where you can write statements such as this;

```
@Provide @MyActivity Class<? extends Activity> provideMyActivityClass() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
     return MyActivitySupportingApiLevel14.class;
    } else {
     return MyCompatibilityActivity.class;
    }
}
```

This approach requires some knowledge of DI but in summary; the provider approach means your code can have a single execution path (i.e. get me the class of the activity the OS should instantiate) and your chosen DI framework will use the instructions under the provider to decide what is the right activity for the build the application is running on. This can introduce a degree of duplication in code but there are plenty of approaches to minimise this including inheritance (everyone knows inheritance is bad right?) and further use of DI with varying implementations for dependencies on your activity which should be modelled as interfaces. Your instantiation code would then look like this;

```
@Inject @MyActivity Class<Activity> myActivity;

... // and later...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, myActivity);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you do not have time get up and running with DI (and DI on Android) then similar results can be achieved with the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Our apps use [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) from Square on Android clients and [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) for Java server-side components. The same chaps were involved in writing both.